# How to ask customers if they want to update their credit card credentials?

Tags: sens, expressions, choix-de-mot, usage, commerce

I'm a bilingual customer service rep & I just got off a French call & I wanted to offer the customer if she wanted to update her credit card on file, I was thinking about saying it:

> *Vous voulez mettre à jour votre information de votre carte de
>   crédit?*

Is that right or is there another way of saying it?

Comment: Whatever formulation you will use, your demand of "credit card update" will sound weird to any French customer. For appropriate translations of such request, more context is needed: precise what is meant by "information".

Comment: @Graffito It's the credit card she has on file for pre-authorized payment & when I pulled up the account I realized her credit card expired

Comment: You may thens say: "La date d'expiration de votre carte bancaire étant dépassée, pouvez-vous nous communiquer la date indiquée sur votre nouvelle carte?"

Comment: @Graffito Est-ce que le numéro est toujours nécessairement le même ? Ce qui est certain, c'est qu'il faut une nouvelle carte...

Comment: @Relaxed - En France, lors d'un renouvellement, le numéro de carte est toujours modifié pour des raisons de sécurité. En dehors d'un acte de vente, demander un numéro de carte par téléphone est une démarche totalement anormale et seuls des gens mal informés répondront à de telles demandes.

Comment: @Graffito En fait je croyais la même chose et je m'apprêtais à l'écrire avant de vérifier et il se trouve que mes deux dernières cartes (il est vrai non-françaises) ont bien le même numéro. Mais cela ne fait que renforcer mon objection, à quoi servirait donc la nouvelle date d'expiration ? Ça n'a pas de sens de demander ça si on ne demande pas également le nouveau numéro !

Comment: It makes PERFECT sense for a company to ask a customer to update the credit card info they have on file for pre-authorized payment . This post was for grammatical purposes, not for you to criticize corporate policies. As much as I appreciate your help you deviated from the purpose of this topic in a very unnecessary way

Comment: Amazon(.fr) refers to a customer’s “moyen(s) de paiement” instead of their “carte(s) de credit” & instead of “mettre à jour” (update) it uses “modifier” (&/or the longer “effectuer des modifications sur”), so perhaps French consumers would be more comfortable responding to the following: “Voulez-vous modifier votre/vos moyen/s de paiement associé/s à votre compte?” (but, w/out getting too deep into your company’s policies, this question can be answered safely on the phone ONLY IF the **customer** initiated the call. A cold call received by the consumer asking such a question would be phishing)

Comment: @PapaPoule J'avais hésiter à ajouter quelque chose comme ça, c'est une excellente suggestion qui mérite probablement de faire l'objet d'une autre réponse !

Answer (score 1):

A few things in your sentence sound awkward:

- “Vous voulez mettre à jour” is common in French but a bit colloquial, I would expect a customer rep to say “Voulez-vous mettre à jour […] ?”.
- Perhaps surprisingly, “votre information de votre carte de crédit” is incorrect and would not be uttered by a native French speaker. You would use only one “votre” so “les informations de votre carte de crédit” (still a bit odd), “votre information de carte de crédit“ (OK) or simply “votre carte de crédit” (best).

Putting all together, I would say:

> Voulez-vous mettre à jour votre carte de crédit ?

Unless you work for a bank, it should be completely unambiguous and clearly refer to the information on file.

It seems my initial suggestion is far from consensual. I still think “les informations de votre carte de crédit” is inappropriate. One alternative could be:

> Voulez-vous mettre à jour les informations *concernant* votre carte de crédit ?

But in light of your most recent comments, the following would also work well:

> Voulez-vous changer la carte de crédit associée à votre compte ?

Comment: "Voulez vous mettre à jour les informations de votre carte de crédit ?" est plus proche de l'idée initiale je pense.

Comment: @user9162 “les informations” est certainement beaucoup plus naturel que “l'information”, j'ai corrigé. Je ne suis cependant pas convaincu que ce soit une bonne façon de poser cette question.

Comment: je pense que c'est la bonne façon, avec "les informations". Sans "information", on ne sait pas de quoi on parle

Comment: @Nikko Je ne suis pas du tout d'accord. Ça peut paraitre logique sur un plan formel et grammatical mais en réalité, on sait exactement de quoi on parle, tandis que “les informations de votre carte de crédit” suggère plutôt qu'on voudrait changer le nom du détenteur de la carte ou quelque autre information présente sur la carte elle-même. S'il faut absolument éviter d'être trop elliptique, on pourrait à la rigueur dire “changer la carte associée à votre compte” ou quelque chose comme ça.

Comment: Au vu des commentaires, j'ai ajouté d'autres suggestions. Mais je continue à trouver “les informations de votre carte” inutilement verbeux, confus et pas plus précis que ça. Il s'agit bien d'associer une nouvelle carte à un compte, pas de changer celle que la personne a en main !

Comment: Je soutiens les commentaires : on ne met pas à jour une carte de crédit, on met à jour des informations.

Comment: @Eria Et comment la phrase “mettre à jour votre carte de crédit” pourrait-elle donc être interprétée selon vous ?

Comment: @Relaxed Je ne sais pas. Peut-être que la personne comprendrait. Peut-être qu'elle penserait à une vraie "mise à jour", comme celle de la carte vitale en France, c'est-à-dire une modification des données présentes sur la carte. Peut-être autre chose... À partir du moment où le sens d'une phrase n'est pas clair, chacun l'interprète comme il le veut/peut. Une phrase claire ne laisse pas de place à l'interprétation.

Comment: @Eria Comme je l'ai déjà dit, “mise à jour des informations de votre carte de crédit” suggère justement quelque chose comme cette mise à jour de la carte vitale, c'est précisément la raison pour laquelle “mettre à jour votre carte de crédit” me semblait plus clair… J'ai déjà fait d'autres propositions encore plus précises mais je ne vois pas bien en quoi cette distinction entre mettre à jour une carte et mettre à jour des informations nous avance et je continue à penser qu'il n'y a aucune raison de prétendre qu'on ne sait pas de quoi on parle sans le mot “information”.

Comment: @Relaxed Je pense donc qu'on restera en désaccord.